# How to add category argument to shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters, shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode that displays my post type: advanced_topic but want to add the category parameter such as

**[advanced-topics category="parole"]**

to display only topics under that category.

This is the code I have so far but I feel like I'm missing something as it's not working... Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
function display_advanced_topics(){

    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'category_name' => 'criminal-records' ), $args ) ); // $categoryName variable will be initialized to 'criminal-records' if the shortcode is missing the 'category' parameter

    $string = '';
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'advanced_topic',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => $categoryName
    );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    $string .= '<div class="advanced-topics">';
    while( $query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();

        $string .= 
        '<div class="row advanced-topic">'
                    .'<div class="content">
                            <div class="title"><?php get_the_title(); ?></div>
                        </div>'
                .'</div>';
    }
            $string .= '</div>';

}
wp_reset_postdata();
return $string;
}
add_shortcode( 'advanced-topics', 'display_advanced_topics' );
```

Comment: You should read the Codex on how to make a shortcode with attributes. Yours is missing. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts

Comment: I did and that is how I started this shortcode, but I can't seem to find what I am missing?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Always is good to use

   ```
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
       ini_set('display_error', 1);
   ```
2. wrong quotes

   ```
       ob_start();
       get_the_title()
       $the_title = ob_get_clean();
       $string .= 
       '<div class="row advanced-topic">'
                   .'<div class="content">
                           <div class="title">'. $the_title .'</div>
                       </div>'
               .'</div>';
   ```

if `get_the_title()` prints results you must use [`ob_get_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: Hi, so it is printing results but it's printing all the ones with the initial default category "criminal-records" only.  I tried [advanced-topics category="parole"] to display from "parole" category but it doesn't seem to be taking the parameter.

Comment: I improved the code. You just can not assign a print result to a variable. (In simplification) Every print you can assign to variable by `ob_start()` - `ob_get_clean()`;